# How to add url parameters that show which links was clicked for marketing conversions

Tags: facebook, url, google-analytics, facebook-marketing-api

I have a shopify store and I am going to start running ads on different platforms and accounts. I wanted to know if there was a way or platform that allows me to create different urls for each of the different marketing campaigns I want to post on so that I can see which link was clicked in google analytics or shopify analytics.

Example:
I want a link for facebook and a different link for Ig that I post in marketing ads so that when I go on to google analytics, I can see if people are coming from facebook or instagram.

Answer (score 1):

What you want are urm tags - Google provides a tool to make them

https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/campaign-url-builder/